# How to access apex:page.showHeader from javascript?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am trying to code

```html
document.getElementById("ap1").showHeader = "true";
```

and using this sf example as a good start, but when I inspect the console.log message and search the 3rd parm "document" there is no id="ap1", in fact I cannot locate the apex:page element/component at all. How can I get at the attributes of 'page' and toggle the header?

```html
<apex:page id="ap1" showHeader="False" sidebar="True">
  <script>
    function cbHandler(input, textid) {
      console.log("cbHandler: ", input, textid,  document.getElementById("ap1:thePanel"), document);
      if (input.checked) {
        document.getElementById(textid).style.fontWeight = "bold";
      } else {
        document.getElementById(textid).style.fontWeight = "normal";
      }
    }
  </script>

  <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
    <label for="checkbox">Click this box to change text font:</label>
    <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" onClick="cbHandler(this,'{!$Component.thePanel}');" />
  </apex:outputPanel>

  <apex:outputPanel id="thePanel" layout="block">
    Change my font weight!
  </apex:outputPanel>

</apex:page>
```

I found this

```html
//header
document.getElementById('AppBodyHeader').style.display = 'none';
//sidebar
document.getElementById('sidebarDiv').style.display = 'none';
```

but these elements do not exist within the doc or at least I cannot get to them

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `?isdtp=mn` attribute?